# Creating my own buttons?

Tags: texmaker

For example, if I wish to use the isomorphism symbol in Texmaker, I can type `\simeq` myself, or I can just click the symbol on the left hand tab.

I want to repeatedly write `$<_{\omega}$`. So it looks like `<` but with an omega subscript. Is there any way to attach such a command to a button, so it's only one click away like `\simeq`?

Comment: In the left hand tab go to user button, then right click and chose add tag.